# Very weird logical error in WPF GridViewColumnHeader

Tags: wpf, xaml, visibility

I have custom treelistview and I put a checkbox in the first column of my treelistview. everything is ok but when I want to hide the checkbox column for other purpose (using variable SelectEnable) , it does not hide correctly(it hides but a blank area remains). This Problem happens when I load the data (I mean when treelistview is empty, the column is hidden).
 here is some pieces of my xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="checkboxColumnStyle"
       TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
  <Setter Property="Width"
          Value="0" />
  <Setter Property="Visibility"
          Value="Hidden" />

  <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource  AncestorType=UserControl},Path=SelectEnable}"
                 Value="False">
      <Setter Property="Visibility"
              Value="Hidden" />
      <Setter Property="Width"
              Value="0" />
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource  AncestorType=UserControl},Path=SelectEnable}"
                 Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Visibility"
              Value="Visible" />
      <Setter Property="Width"
              Value="30" />
    </DataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<DataTemplate x:Key="CellTemplate_checkBox">
  <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Style="{DynamicResource checkboxStyle}"
            Tag="{Binding}"
            Checked="CheckBox_Checked"
            Unchecked="CheckBox_Checked" />
</DataTemplate>

<GridViewColumnCollection x:Key="gvcc">
  <GridViewColumn  CellTemplate="{StaticResource CellTemplate_checkBox}">

    <GridViewColumnHeader Style="{DynamicResource checkboxColumnStyle}"
                          MaxWidth="0">
      <CheckBox x:Name="chechBoxAll"
                Style="{DynamicResource checkboxStyle}"
                Checked="chechBoxAll_Checked"
                Unchecked="chechBoxAll_Checked" />
    </GridViewColumnHeader>
  </GridViewColumn>
  <!--Other Columns -->
</GridViewColumnCollection>
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You probably want `Visibility.Collapsed` instead of `Visibility.Hidden`.

`Hidden` means the element is there but cannot be seen (similar to `Opacity` of 0), whereas `Collapsed` causes the layout arrangement to happen as though the element does not exist (no width and no height).

Comment: but i set width to 0. I check this solution out.

Comment: I tried to set visibility to "collapsed" , but it didn't help me. I can email you my code, if you like.

Comment: @alifattahian Can you post an image or a link to an image that highlights the part you see and don't like?

Comment: Here is the images of my software ([after](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=25CA1C5D6C3F1650!123&authkey=!AJ2fGYhoovT9WlA) and [before](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=25CA1C5D6C3F1650!124&authkey=!AA0R4f-NavVtILQ))

Comment: I found an article that is helpful. but I didn't try it. here is [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/atc_avalon_team/archive/2006/04/11/573037.aspx)

Comment: The above link helped me. GridViewColumnHeader resize automatically, even if we set width of the GridViewColumnHeader . so I derive a FixedGridViewColumn from GridViewColumn and I binded it to a widthOfCheckbox. I couldn't find another way to fix my problem. what is your openion?